# PHP SimpleXML Parsing Issue

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am getting the following returned from an api I am working with.. However using SIMPLEXML I am unable to access the values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Response Version="1.0">
   <DateTime>2/13/2013 10:37:24 PM</DateTime>
   <Contact_ID>151-233-DD</Contact_ID>
   <Quote_ID>ojc332-ewied-23e3ed</Quote_ID>
   <Status>Failure</Status>
   <Reason>Incorrect Contact ID</Reason>
</Response>
```

I am setting this up with:

```
$variable = new SimpleXMLElement($results);
```

SIMPLEXML is giving me the following instead of what I expect to be 
    $variable->DateTime:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2/13/2013 10:37:24 PM 151-233-DD 0jc332-ewied-23e3ed Failure Incorrect Contract ID )
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: as @Rikesh mentioned *Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content*

Answer (score 6):

Seems cause of encoding type `utf-16` while content has `utf-8`.

So you need to change your encode type,

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <Response Version="1.0">
  <DateTime>2/13/2013 10:37:24 PM</DateTime>
  <Contact_ID>151-233-DD</Contact_ID>
  <Quote_ID>ojc332-ewied-23e3ed</Quote_ID>
  <Status>Failure</Status>
  <Reason>Incorrect Contact ID</Reason>
 </Response>'; 
$xml = simplexml_load_string(preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $string));
```

[Codepad DEMO](http://codepad.org/5i75PoAm).

Also It can be done using `utf8_encode`,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($string));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually just encoded the result from the call using utf8_encode($result) and all is well.

Comment: @Nikon0266 - That can be the alternative too. Welcome :)

Comment: Actually I think it was middle of the night delusion.. I thought this was working but it isnt.. 

So I have narrowed it down to everything is formatted correctly until I try to load it with SimpleXML. Then I get back only:

    SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2/13/2013 10:37:24 PM 151-233-DD 0jc332-ewied-23e3ed Failure Incorrect Contract ID )

I cant access these elements individually.. I am lost on this..

However, if I create a string from the result and load it is fine.. Only when I use the variable returned by curl.

Comment: Very well done, thank you.

I had XML data with `encoding="utf-16"` in it and for some reason PHP `simplexml_load_string` didn't want to parse it so your regular expressions fixed that problem.

It was response data from Sage Payments USA (SEVD)

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing only one XML element (hint the name of the class). You need to load the whole string as a XML document. Here is how:

```
<?php

$result= <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response Version="1.0">
   <DateTime>2/13/2013 10:37:24 PM</DateTime>
   <Contact_ID>151-233-DD</Contact_ID>
   <Quote_ID>ojc332-ewied-23e3ed</Quote_ID>
   <Status>Failure</Status>
   <Reason>Incorrect Contact ID</Reason>
</Response>
XML;

$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($result, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

Then you can use the DOM interface to access the various components in the document.

e.g.

```
$dates = dom->getElementsByTagName('DateTime');
```

This will fetch an array containing all the `DateTime` elements.

**EDIT**

Oops - `$dates` will be an object of `DOMNodeList`.

You can then use the various methods to access the nodes and fetch the attributes.

Comment: I did give this a try.. however I get an error from dom saying that "Object of class DOMNodeList". as mentioned above it works fine if I create a string of the results and load those. But if I used the variable returned by Curl I get this error..