# how to get xml node value php

Tags: php, xml

I've fired a curl request. My code is

```
$URL = "http://demo.com";

            $ch = curl_init($URL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xmlLeadCloud");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
```

Below I am getting the XML in `$output` variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LeadCloud>
    <InsuranceSvcRs>
        <PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs>
            <MsgStatus>
                <MsgStatusCd>Success</MsgStatusCd>
                <Payout>17.40</Payout>
                <BuyerLeadId>4ded4da790c6fasasasas322</BuyerLeadId>
                <BuyerId>34</BuyerId>
            </MsgStatus>
        </PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs>
    </InsuranceSvcRs>
</LeadCloud>
```

How could I get `MsgStatusCd` element's value from it. So far I've tried.

```
$s = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
echo $s->InsuranceSvcRs->PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs->MsgStatus->MsgStatusCd; die; //not working
```

Comment: and you are doing it right, what is the problem ?

Comment: It is not showing output `$s->InsuranceSvcRs->PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs->MsgStatus->MsgStatusCd;` In my case it should show `Success`

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Getting message `SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in `..

Comment: Take a look [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e46b6b2fe0c37265ecf69e70383daf084207198b), you just need to change encoding to `utf-8`, and use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6284593/3113793) for changing.

Comment: @chris85, yes my reporting is on.

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't getting a warning but you need to change the encoding. Comment above has a thread using a regex to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the output to a string to get its value:

```
echo (string) $xml->InsuranceSvcRs->PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs->MsgStatus->MsgStatusCd;
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/PmBw4F) where it prints:

```
Success
```

Comment: You should never write a code like this against external API's prone to changes. Code like this will inevitably lead to "trying to get property of non-object" and as a result, you will loose control over your code path introducing exceptional state where there should be none.

Comment: @nickb It's not working in my case. Will you please suggest me another way

Comment: @Vineet the encoding of the XML is throwing it off. The demo here has altered the encoding of the XML to utf8.

Comment: @nickb API output is not in my hand. How could I convert `utf-16` to `utf-8` ?

Comment: @Vineet - You can modify the value from utf-16 to utf-8 as suggested in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869227/php-simplexml-parsing-issue), but it seems hacky. You might want to consider an alternative than the simplexml parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to access this data (see PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) entry).

The reason why your accessor does not work is that the XML you are receiving is a data array, hence,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LeadCloud> <!-- ROOT -->
    <InsuranceSvcRs> <!-- Zero or more -->
        <PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs> <!-- Zero or more -->
            <MsgStatus> <!-- Zero or more -->
                <MsgStatusCd>Success</MsgStatusCd> <!-- Zero or one -->
                <Payout>17.40</Payout> <!-- Zero or one -->
                <BuyerLeadId>4ded4da790c6fasasasas322</BuyerLeadId> <!-- Zero or one -->
                <BuyerId>34</BuyerId> <!-- Zero or one -->
            </MsgStatus>
        </PersHealthPolicyQuoteInqRs>
    </InsuranceSvcRs>
</LeadCloud>
```

and should be accessed as such.